# How to solve $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}\geq \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

any impulses, suggestions? I have been trying for a while but it doesn't get me anywhere...

Kind regards

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/297916/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563096/42969

Comment: Don't you have to prove it via Induction?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $$f(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}$$.

Now try and show that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x>0$

Comment: That's exactly what I want to prove. I can't use differentiation however. I tried proving it by induction, but I fail to prove this inequality

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Prove that $f(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ is strictly increasing for x>0

Comment: That's exactly what I want to prove. I can't use differentiation however. I tried proving it by induction, but I fail to prove this inequality

Answer (score 0):

log both sides and rearrange:sufficient to prove
$$\frac{n+2}{n+1}\ge\ln(\frac{\frac{n+2}{n+1}}{\frac{n+3}{n+2}})$$
which is
$$\ln(e^{\frac{n+2}{n+1}})\ge\ln(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+3)})$$
exponential both sides and LHS$>2>$RHS